# finding the optimum solution of a scene similar to traveling salesman

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a weighted undirected connected graph, each vertex has `M` goods and needs `N` goods.

For some vertexes, `M >= N` so that they can meet their requirement. For the other vertexes, we have to transport goods from "rich" vertex to them because requirement has to be satisfied.

However, transport has cost. The cost equals to the weight of the edge multiply the number of goods transported.

Assume the number of goods all vertexes have is bigger than the number of goods all vertexes need. I need a transport plan that can make all vertexes meet their needs with least cost.

Any idea on this? Thanks for your time!

UPDATE:

To make this problem simpler, if vertex is some place in a map, the edge between 2 vertexes is not a road between 2 place in the map, but the shortest path between these 2 place. So the graph turned into a complete graph.

Then there is no need to do transport between "rich" vertexes and between "pool" vertexes. We can regard this graph as bipartite graph.

Comment: For a given node w/ a goods excess finding the shortest route to a node with a goods deficit should not be costly or difficult. So - make a list of <node, cost> where cost is the cost of the shortest route for that node. Sort by cost (a heap keyed on cost would do it). Select the node w/ the least cost; deliver as many goods as possible on that route; recalculate the minimal route for that node (if it still has an excess) and put it back in the collection. Repeat until all the goods are distributed.

Comment: @mcwyrm I think that approach (greedy solution) is broken, if a node gets balanced where the following conditions are met: a) the "drained" node is part of other optimal routes; b) the balanced node has other good options, which weren't used, because they are not optimal; c) the other nodes, that are affected by condition a) now need to use bad pathes to nodes, that were mentioned in condition b).

Comment: @SME_Dev I see that you are right.

Comment: @cloud is the transportation cost directly payed, after each travel? or is it just accumulated virtually.

Comment: @cloud another question is: you mentioned a traveling salesman. is there a entity that travels sequentially? It seems that an empty transport has no costs. so it does not matter how often each node is passed.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch The cost is just accumulated virtually. And there is NO entity travels sequentially. An empty transport has no cost but also has no contribution. And yes, it doesn't matter how often each node is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min cost flow algorithm to get optimal solution:

1. The graph is bipartite: the first set is for "rich" vertices. The second set is for vertices that can receive additional goods. There is an edge between each vertex from the first set and each vertex of the second set with `capacity = INF` and `cost = distance between them`.
2. There is also an edge from the source to each vertex from the first set with `capacity = number of goods that must be removed` and `cost = 0`.
3. There is an edge from each vertex from the second set and the sink with `capacity = number of goods it can receive` and `cost = 0`.

The answer is the cost of maximal flow in this graph(from the source to the sink). It is also possible to reconstruct a transport plan itself by looking at the amount of flow going through each edge.

Comment: How to define the `source` and `sink` vertexes? Are they virtual?

Comment: @cloud No. They are just two other vertices(neither from the first set not from the second one).